# Python, shapely library: is it possible to do an affine operation on shape polygon?

Tags: python, gdal, geometry, shapely, affine-transformation

I am trying to create a rotated rectangle in lat/lon coordinates.

Basically, I have the coordinates of the center and rotation angle around the center.

Is it possible to do using, shapely or gdal, or something else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Shapely's [**`affinity` module**](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#affine-transformations) supports affine transformations on any geometry, for example:

```
from shapely import affinity
from shapely.geometry import LineString

# Example geometry
line = LineString([(1, 3), (1, 1), (4, 1)])

# Rotate 30 degrees CCW from origin at the center of bbox
line_rot_center = affinity.rotate(line, 30, 'center')

# Rotate from origin at (1, 1)
line_rot_11 = affinity.rotate(line, 30, (1, 1))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, a rotation in (lat, lon) is not performed with an affine transformation.  You either have to project the data and rotate the projected coordinates or else perform a spherical rotation.

Comment: Oh right, I missed the (lat, lon) part of the question. I've never seen a affine transformation function built for geographic inputs, so the tips you provided are essential.

Comment: Since v1.2.17, Shapely has had affine transformations, although they're not documented yet - https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/master/shapely/affinity.py

Comment: Also see the author's blog: http://sgillies.net/blog/1168/shapely-1-2-17

Comment: @AlexL type `help(shapely.affinity)`. Actually I'm nearly done preparing the manual update for the module.

Comment: @MikeToews Ah, I missed the bit that said you wrote it. Great work - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Sextante has a tool that might work. It is called Transform, under the "Tools for Vector layers". To run the command, define the angle, anchor point, scale factor and translation. Sextante is an extension to gvsig, openjump, udig, others. It also runs from the command-line.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any features in Python or Shapely to do so but you can do this with JTS (Java Topology Suite) http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html (GEOS, the lib used by Shapely is a port of JTS but JTS have more functions)

You can download the soft here http://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/ and launch testbuilder.sh or testbuilder.bat depending on your OS to play for discovering. After you understood, the basics you will have to do the same without GUI but with Java programming only.

http://geoscript.org/ may help you to make the glue beetween python code and java (because one implementation use Jython)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the gdal python bindings to do affine transformations ([Link](https://gdal.org/tutorials/osr_api_tut.html)).

Since it is built on top of proj/geos/gdal you can do the same things as in shapely + more.

Answer (score 1):

Grass can do it using [v.transform](http://www.phygeo.uni-hannover.de/grass/grass65/manuals/html65_user/v.transform.html).