# Rotating geometry to specific angle using pyqgis?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geometry, editing, python-2.7

I do not know how to rotate a geometry using pyqgis.

Is there any sample/example code available to show me how?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23587/how-do-i-rotate-the-polygon-about-an-anchor-point-using-python-script

Answer (score 3):

While not in Python, you can review the C++ code used by [the Rotate Feature map tool](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/qgsmaptoolrotatefeature.cpp).

**Note:**

The tool is interactive, so it uses the user input *press* and *move* events (e.g. like with a mouse) to calculate the degree of rotation to be applied.

The `QgsMapToolRotateFeature::canvasReleaseEvent`, where the calculated rotation is applied to the feature, is probably the code you are looking for.

Comment: QgsMapToolRotateFeature option is seems to be semi-automatic[Using mouse events]. But I want to a rotate feature automatically to a specific angle.

Comment: Look at the code in the `canvasReleaseEvent` function. L203-210 define the affine transformation, L224-243 apply the transformation to each point in the geometry. This is what you'd need. Or, as you say, you can do it using Shapely.

Answer (score 2):

It can be accomplish, by using a python package named shapely.

Eg:
shapely.affinity.rotate(ring,degres,origin='centroid',use_radians=False)