# How to rotate a geometry created by the geometry builder in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geometry, geometry-generator, rotate

This topic goes into making polygons based on point locations;
[Using QGIS Geometry Generator to get rectangle from point?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194519/using-qgis-geometry-generator-to-get-rectangle-from-point)
Is there a way to apply a rotation to the geometry generated? I have a field that contains a 0-360 degree rotation value and would like to rotate my built geometries based on that value.

Comment: I think I asked my question wrong, sorry. I am looking to use the geometry generator in the styles dialog to build polygons from points with attributes for "length" and "width". I can build the polygons using the answer provided in the link but my point file has an additional field called "rotation". I would like to rotate the polygons generated based on the rotation field in the attributes for each feature.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/shapely.html#module-shapely.affinity) which is provided as a python package. You would interested in the rotate function:

```
shapely.affinity.rotate(geom, angle, origin='center', use_radians=False)¶
Returns a rotated geometry on a 2D plane.  
The angle of rotation can be specified in either degrees (default) or   radians by setting use_radians=True. Positive angles are counter-clockwise and   negative are clockwise rotations.  
The point of origin can be a keyword ‘center’ for the bounding box center   (default), ‘centroid’ for the geometry’s centroid, a Point object or a   coordinate tuple (x0, y0).  
The affine transformation matrix for 2D rotation is:  
/ cos(r) -sin(r) xoff | sin(r) cos(r) yoff | 0 0 1 /
where the offsets are calculated from the origin Point(x0, y0)
```

This [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/139494/35779) provides an example possible setup

Also, this is a [C++ solution](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/qgsmaptoolrotatefeature.cpp) you can check out as well.

Answer (score 2):

- if you don't know Python, you can directly use the [Affine Transformations](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgsAffine/) or the [Vector Transformation](https://github.com/pnakis/qgis_vector_transform) plugins (and others as [Scaling and rotating vector layers in qgis using qgsAffine](http://hydrogeotools.blogspot.be/2015/03/scaling-and-rotating-vector-layers-in.html) for example)

[image]

- if you know Python, before using Shapely, you can use the `rotate` function of a QgsGeometry in  PyQGIS ([Rotación de archivos vectoriales con método ‘rotate’ de QgsGeometry en PyQGIS](https://joseguerreroa.wordpress.com/2015/10/06/rotacion-de-archivos-vectoriales-con-metodo-rotate-de-qgsgeometry-en-pyqgis/), in Spanish but the scripts are universal) or the [Affine](https://github.com/sgillies/affine) Python module.