# Problem rotating features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, editing

I'm trying to rotate multiple features  in a certain angle, but each on its own pivot, is there a way to do it in ArcMap? Whenever I try to select the features and use the rotate tool all of them rotate on the same axis.

Comment: I am afraid that you can only have one anchor point for all selected features. If you need to rotate a lot of feature, try some scripts http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23587/how-do-i-rotate-the-polygon-about-an-anchor-point-using-python-script

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that you are asking for a script based answer, so I did not mark as duplicate, however, I the only way to do this using ArcGIS is with a script (see [How to Rotate Features in ArcGIS Using Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/how-to-rotate-features-in-arcgis-for-desktop-using-arcpy)), though there do seem to be references to third party tools out there as well (see [this ESRI help link](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=987&t=210244) that references what appears to be a pay tool).