# How to rotate multiple polygons about their respective anchor points

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rotate a feature in ArcGIS 10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/rotate-a-feature-in-arcgis-10)

I have a set of polygons, which are to be rotated in eight directions, about their respective fixed anchor points.

I am able to do so for a single polygon using Affine (Scale, Rotate, Translation), but unable to do so for multiple polygons in the same layer.

Can anyone provide a python script, for the same.

Regards,
KSV

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13383/python-shapely-library-is-it-possible-to-do-an-affine-operation-on-shape-polyg