# Find Properties of Nearest Line Segments to Point in Python

Tags: python, shapefile, intersection, shapely, fiona

I have been trying to find a workable Python approach to finding nearest line segments to one (or more) points, and came accross @gene's solution to @RustyMagoo's problem [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81613/find-nearest-line-segments-to-point):

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, mapping, shape
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
from shapely import affinity
import fiona

sweep_res = 10  # sweep resolution (degrees)
focal_pt = Point(0, 0)  # radial sweep centre point
sweep_radius = 100.0  # sweep radius

# create the radial sweep lines
line = LineString([(focal_pt.x,focal_pt.y), \
                   (focal_pt.x, focal_pt.y + sweep_radius)])

sweep_lines = [affinity.rotate(line, i, (focal_pt.x, focal_pt.y)) \
               for i in range(0, 360, sweep_res)]

radial_sweep = cascaded_union(sweep_lines)

# load the input lines and combine them into one geometry
input_lines = fiona.open("input_lines.shp")
input_shapes = [shape(f['geometry']) for f in input_lines]
all_input_lines = cascaded_union(input_shapes)

perimeter = []
# traverse each radial sweep line and check for intersection with input lines
for radial_line in radial_sweep:
    inter = radial_line.intersection(all_input_lines)

    if inter.type == "MultiPoint":
       # radial line intersects at multiple points
       inter_dict = {}
       for inter_pt in inter:
           inter_dict[focal_pt.distance(inter_pt)] = inter_pt
       # save the nearest intersected point to the sweep centre point
       perimeter.append(inter_dict[min(inter_dict.keys())])

    if inter.type == "Point":
       # radial line intersects at one point only
       perimeter.append(inter)

    if inter.type == "GeometryCollection":
       # radial line doesn't intersect, so skip
       pass

# combine the nearest perimeter points into one geometry
solution = cascaded_union(perimeter)

# save the perimeter geometry
schema = {'geometry': 'MultiPoint', 'properties': {'test': 'int'}}
with fiona.open('perimeter.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema) as e:
     e.write({'geometry':mapping(solution), 'properties':{'test':1}})
```

What I need in addition is to extract the nearest lines' attributes/ properties, like id, name, shape, etc. For example, if my shapefile of lines are rivers, and attributes of the rivers are name, length, data about the amount of water passing each day, etc. How would I go about extracting this information using the method proposed by @gene/@RustyMagoo?